# Shibboleth authentication in Symfony using an attribute

Tags: security, ldap, symfony, shibboleth

I want to implement a Shibboleth login to parts of a Symfony site. There are a lot of apps using the LDAP accounts, so each app needs to be able to check if the logged in user has access to it (not just check there is a user logged in).

We were looking at using an attribute something like 'unscoped-affiliation' that would have a value of something like "staff;program1;masteradmin;program2" or so. If I am doing the admin for program1, I want to check it is in the list.

Any suggestions?

Comment: All you site should be under shibboleth access?

Comment: No, just the admin parts, the rest are public access. I have set up the access_control for these parts in security.yml, so just need to make shibboleth do the auth/login to set the roles (ROLE_ADMIN at the moment).